# Integral with limits from tendline

Tags: excel, math, integral, vba

I have a graph that is similar to the one below that is generated through 15-20 points (varies). I am interested in obtaining the area under the curve from 0 to the last x value.

One that I have been doing it is create a 3rd-6th order (varies) from excel trendline and calculate the integral that way. For example:

```
Equation: y = (c3 * x^3) + (c2 * x^2) + (c1 * x^1) + b

c3: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2,3}),1)

c2: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2,3}),1,2)

C1: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2,3}),1,3)

b: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2,3}),1,4)
```

Trapezoidal integral is not possible since step size is very large as I do not have control over the number of points.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Image:

[image]

Comment: Are the points equally spaced? I don't like the idea of using regression since the resulting curves are not guaranteed to pass though the points. Perhaps you can use something like Simpson's method. You could also do something like piecewise cubic interpolation, which will give you a smooth curve passing through the points.

Comment: No they are not evenly spaced, the results are output from another software. A piece-wise function does provide better results but that doubles the required code needed for little improvement in accuracy.